# appSettings in Web.config and Web.Release.config

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, appsettings

Trying to get simple `<appSettings>` for dev vs. prod.

My `Web.config`:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="hello" value="debug" />
</appSettings>
```

My `Web.Release.config`:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="hello" value="prod" />
</appSettings>
```

(both under `<configuration>`)

When I have it in Debug mode, and run my MVC site, I can do a simple `return Content(WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["hello"]);` in my `HomeController.Index` and it returns `dev`. If I switch the mode to `Release` it still returns `dev`. I'd like to simulate prod mode without actually publishing to prod.

Comment: There is no good way to do this, and there's a very strong argument that you really shouldn't be doing it either. Ultimately, IIS will only look at a file called `web.config` so you are limited to using that file. You can preview the transformed file and copy/paste it in, of course remembering to undo after you've tested it.

Answer (score 20):

In the build-specific Web.config file, you have to tell it how to transform the base .config file. So to do what you ask, your `Web.Release.config` file should look like this:

```
<appSettings>
  <add key="hello" value="prod" xdt:Transform="SetAttributes" xdt:Locator="Match(key)" />
</appSettings>
```

In the above code the `SetAttributes` transform will change the attributes of any element that matches the `key` attribute containing the value `hello`.

Comment: Just an FYI, this does not work with F5 debugging, it works during publish.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from  **.NET 4.7.1** feature called **Configuration builder** is supported which gives developer ability to load configuration not only from `Web.Release.Cong` but basically from any source. [Read more about .NET Framework 4.7.1 ASP.NET and Configuration features](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/dotnet/2017/09/13/net-framework-4-7-1-asp-net-and-configuration-features/)